# How I restrict the user to only enter Date Field in angular bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui

I am new in angular and I stuck at point where I am unable to restrict the user to enter valid date manually. It sets the date as undefined for empty, characters as well as invalid date entered by the user. The date format I have mentioned is MM-dd-yyyy. Even if I enter 85/34/2102 it assumes this as a date and takes some junk value instead of validating and throwing an error.

my code of angular date-picker in html

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{clCtrl.format}}" 
   ng-model="clCtrl.QualityExpirationDate" is-open="clCtrl.openedQualityDate" 
   min-date="clCtrl.minDate" datepicker-options="clCtrl.dateOptions"  
   ng-required="true" close-on-date-selection="true" show-button-bar="false" />
```

and code in angular controller side

```
self.dateOptions = {
        formatYear: 'yy',
        startingDay: 1
    };

    self.formats = ['MM-dd-yyyy', 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'MM.dd.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
    self.format = self.formats[0]; 

self.openQualityDate = function ($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
        self.openedQualityDate = true;
    };


 self.toggleMin = function () {
        self.minDate = self.minDate ? null : new Date();
    };
    self.toggleMin();

    self.clear = function () {

        self.QualityExpirationDate = null;
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a 'readonly' attribute to the input field:

```
<input type="text" readonly class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{clCtrl.format}}" ng-model="clCtrl.QualityExpirationDate" is-open="clCtrl.openedQualityDate" min-date="clCtrl.minDate" datepicker-options="clCtrl.dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-on-date-selection="true" show-button-bar="false" />
```

If you want to allow user input but restrict to valid dates you could add this to your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('dt', function(val) {
  $scope.isValidDate =  isNaN(new Date(val).getTime());
});
```

then use the 'isValidDate' scope property to show/hide a message and/or disable submission, or whatever you want to do.

Of course it would be better to abstract this validation into a directive so it could easily be reused on all your date fields.

Comment: we are giving the facility to the user so that he enter the date manually as well select from the calendar.

Comment: if we use readonly attribute then user can't enter the date values ,here we are giving the user the facility to enter the date manually as well select from the calendar.